# add pagination in wordpress page template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, pagination, terms, page-template

I am using custom page to display my taxonomy terms the terms are displaying fine but
i dont want the terms to all show in one page i want 2 terms per page but the pagination is not working and its showing all the terms on 1 page

this is the code that i am using custom page

```
<?php /*Template Name: terms-List*/ ?>
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="container">

  <header class="page-header">

      <h1 class="page-title">terms list</h1>

  </header>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

<?php 
  $terms = get_terms([

   'taxonomy' => 'books',

    'hide_empty' => false,

  ]);

   foreach ( $terms as $term) {
?>

<div class="col-lg-5th col-md-5th col-sm-5th col-xs-5th">

  <div class="block-item">

   <div class="hover"></div>

     <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term);?>" title="<?php echo $term->name;?>">

       <?php $poster = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'photo-url', true );
       if($poster){?>

    <img width="200" height="283" src="<?php echo $poster; ?>"class="attachment- 
    movie size-movie wp-post-image" alt=""> 

<?php

} else { ?>

    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default- 
     thumbnail.png" alt="" />

<?php } ?>

 <div class="title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div>

  </a>

  </div>

</div>

<?php 

}

?>

</div>

 <div class="pagination">

   <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

I am using wpbeginner's pagination code which i have put in functions.php.

```
<?php

  function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

   if( is_singular() )

   return;

   global $wp_query;

   if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )

   return;

   $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    if ( $paged >= 1 )

    $links[] = $paged;

     if ( $paged >= 3 ) {

     $links[] = $paged - 1;

     $links[] = $paged - 2;

   }

      if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {

      $links[] = $paged + 2;

      $links[] = $paged + 1;

   }

      echo '<ul>' . "\n";

      if ( get_previous_posts_link() )

      printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('«') );

      if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {

      $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

      printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( 

      get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

      if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )

      echo '<li>…</li>';

 }

      sort( $links );

      foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {

      $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';

      printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( 

      get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );

  }

      if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )

      echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

      $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';

      printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( 

      get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );

 }

      if ( get_next_posts_link() )

      printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('»') );

      echo '</ul>' . "\n";

 }

?>
```

and this is the code for the taxonomy that i am getting the terms form

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'create_series_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 ); 

function create_series_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

   $labels = array(

    'name' => _x( 'books', 'taxonomy general name' ),

    'singular_name' => _x( 'books', 'taxonomy singular name' ),

    'search_items' =>  __( 'search books' ),

    'all_items' => __( 'all books' ),

    'parent_item' => __( 'parent book' ),

    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'parent book' ),

    'edit_item' => __( 'edit books' ), 

    'update_item' => __( 'update books' ),

    'add_new_item' => __( 'add more books' ),

    'new_item_name' => __( 'book name' ),

    'menu_name' => __( 'books' ),

  );     

  register_taxonomy('books',array('books'), array(

    'hierarchical' => true,

    'labels' => $labels,

    'show_ui' => true,

    'show_admin_column' => true,

    'query_var' => true,

    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books' ),

  ));
 
}

?>
```

It is possible to make a pagination

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? It's barely readable at the moment.

Comment: @fuxia is it good now

Comment: Not really … you don't need spaces between lines, but in front of them when the code happens inside a function or condition.

Comment: @fuxia good now

Comment: @fuxia if you talking about the code in wpbeginner's pagination you can find the code here : https://bit.ly/2YNrpuk and the code for the taxonomy you can find it here : https://bit.ly/32GQXKy